# Security of Database passwords (and other important private strings ) in a java application

Tags: java, string, security, password-protection, decompiling

As you know anyone can access strings in an native application using a hex editor.
In a Java application it is possible to decompile the Bytecodes and access strings and other things (like application logic).
Now when I'm connecting to a database my password is stored in application strings.
How Can I protect these strings (passwords,...) against Hex editors & decompilation?

Thanks

Comment: You can try to protect these strings with obfuscation, but fundamentally speaking there is no strong protection. This is what DRM tries to do, and it generally requires hardware support to be successful.

Comment: What is this successful DRM scheme you speak of and how do I buy some stock? :)  There is no way to protect information you release into the wild from a sufficiently motivated attacker.  If it's that important, put an application server in front of the database.

Comment: You should not store the password inside the application code in the first place.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: so where should I store the username and passowrd for a mysql database? a configuration file? reading that is easier then! a encrypted config. file? so I should embed the decryption algorithm in my application so the it can be read too! :-(

Comment: A configuration file with the approriate filesystem access privileges, so that only privileged users can read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing you release to the public is private.  There is no protection scheme that a sufficiently motivated attacker cannot break.  If anybody had one, they'd be making millions selling it to Hollywood!  (Plenty of people are making millions selling ones that don't work...)

You have three basic options:

1) Design the database with procedures and permissions such that having the direct login doesn't allow the user to do anything they couldn't have done through the application anyway.

2) Tie user accounts to database accounts and have users login with their own username.

3) Put an application server in front of the database.  Your client connects to the application server and calls service methods on it.  So only those functions you expose on the app server are exposed to the public.  This is the standard way of doing things.